# Modal only shows on the first record in the gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a gridview where I retrieve any notes captured. The information is retrieved from the database.

On each record in the gridview, you can view the details of the note by clicking a button (btnViewNotes) and a modal popup shows where all the details of the note are shown.

The problem is that the modal only shows on the first record within the gridview. If I try to view details of the second or third or forth... note, the modal does not want to open. It refresh the page and does a postback. It doesn't even reach my AJAX method (keep in mind this problem only happens after the first record).

This is my code below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNotes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered table-hover" ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="NotesID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NotesID" Visible="false" HeaderText="NotesID" SortExpression="NotesID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" Visible="true" HeaderText="CenterName" SortExpression="CenterName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateModified" Visible="true" HeaderText="DateModified" SortExpression="DateModified" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedBy" Visible="true" HeaderText="ModifiedBy" SortExpression="ModifiedBy" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" Visible="true" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" Visible="true" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="display: none"><%# Eval("NotesID") %></span>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewNotes" ImageUrl="~/assets/images/notes.png" data-toggle="modal" Style="width: 20px; height: 18px;" runat="server" Text="View Notes" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ViewNote">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Viewing note</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="input-10" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Center Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNoteCategory" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="input-10" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Time</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <label for="input-11" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Bill:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxBill" class="form-control" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotesID" style="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" Style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Close</button>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveNote" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnViewNotes").click(function () {
        //var NotesID = $('#txtCentreID').val();
        var NotesID = $(this).closest("tr").find('span').html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ViewNotes.aspx/ViewNote",
            data: "{'NotesID': '" + NotesID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var clb = response.d;
            $(clb).each(function () {
                $('#txtNotesID').val(this.NotesID);
                $('#ddlNoteCategory').val(this.CategoryID);
                $('#txtTime').val(this.Time);
                $('#txtDescription').val(this.Description);
                if (this.Bill === "True") {
                    $("#cbxBill").prop("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $("#cbxBill").prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#ViewNote').modal('toggle');
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please advise how I can show the modal for any of the records after the first record. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve the problem. The way I am creating the onClick button function should be like this:

```
$('[id*=btnViewNotes]').on("click", function () {
//Code here
});
```

If anyone could please explain to me the difference between this way and the way I originally created the button onClick function, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should know is that `ImageButton` is a server control, indicated by `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewNotes" ImageUrl="~/assets/images/notes.png" data-toggle="modal" Style="width: 20px; height: 18px;" 
                 runat="server" Text="View Notes" />
```

This control has rendered HTML like example below (notice the control ID at the end):

```
<input type="image" src="/assets/images/notes.png" 
       id="ctlXX_ContentPlaceHolderName_xxxx_ctrlX_btnViewNotes"
       name="ctlXX$ContentPlaceHolderName$xxxx$ctrlX$btnViewNotes" 
       style="width: 20px; height: 18px;" data-toggle="modal" ... />
```

According to [jQuery selector list](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), `$('#btnViewNotes')` is an [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) which selects single element with ID attribute exactly matches with given name, therefore it will search HTML element with attribute `id="btnViewNotes"` which not found in your page. Additionally, you're using `TemplateField` which repeats the input tag for every row, and each input element requires unique ID.

The recommended way to select element ID when using server control inside GridView's `TemplateField` is using ["ends with selector"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) or ["contains selector"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) with control ID as substring, depending on control ID position:

**Ends with selector**

```
$('[id$=btnViewNotes]').click(function () {
    // other stuff
});
```

**Contains selector**

```
$('[id*=btnViewNotes]').click(function () {
    // other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `toggle` you can use this method to open the bootstrap modal

```
$('#ViewNote').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
});
```

Comment: This does not work even for the first record in the gridview. Just does a postback

Comment: You need to disable auto postback for image button click

Comment: Well the biggest concern is that it doesn't even reach the AJAX method for the second or third... record. Only for the first

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. Please see my solution I posted.